# Slim framework 3 $_SESSION variables

Tags: php, session-variables, slim

is there any possibility to use PHP sessions in Slim v3? If not, what's a good replacement? And if I can use them, where I should put session_start(), on index.php or in files I'm using $_SESSION variables?

Comment: You can certainly use PHP sessions with Slim v3, or any version of Slim for that matter. Best practice is to call session_start() as early as possible, so I would put it in your index.php file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `$_SESSION` within a Slim application with ease. Put `session_start()` at the top of index.php.

Alternatively, there are a number of PSR-7 session middleware components out there such as:

- https://github.com/Ocramius/PSR7Session
- https://github.com/akrabat/rka-slim-session-middleware
- https://github.com/oscarotero/psr7-middlewares#aurasession

Answer (score 0):

Since slim is a "PHP" micro framework so any php function(of core php) will be executed without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();
$_SESSION["your_session_data"] = $your_session_data;
```